# Как реализовать программно отправку письма в Thunderbird?

Tags: python, thunderbird

В Thunderbird есть шаблон письма, как можно реализовать его отправку программно, средствами python?

Comment: https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/91/compose.html#beginnew-messageid-details

Comment: @eri ваш комментарий помог поставьте пожалуйста в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird управляется через механизм web-расширений. Документация на интерфейс для питона находится тут https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/91/compose.html#beginnew-messageid-details